# What action is it to stow or holster a weapon?

Tags: weapons, shadowrun-sr5, actions

What action is it to stow or holster a weapon in Shadowrun 5e?

It doesn't appear to be listed in the combat section of the core rulebook, and it's not mentioned in adept powers like rapid draw.

Is it generally assumed to fall under the "ready a weapon" rules as a simple action? If possible, I'd like a RAW answer.

Answer (score 5):

### It's a Simple Action

As said in the Ready Weapon action on p165 of the core rulebook:

> Readying entails drawing a firearm from a holster, drawing a throwing or melee weapon from a sheath, picking up any kind of weapon, or generally preparing any kind of weapon for use. A weapon must be ready before it can be used. Weapons not held in a traditional holster may require a Complex Action to ready at the gamemaster’s discretion.

There's no explicit description for holstering a weapon. The closest you could come is by using the Pick Up / Put Down Object action. It seems the designers are of the mindset that holstering a weapon will happen outside of combat.

Comment: This describes taking a weapon out for use. Is it explicitly described anywhere what action it is to put a weapon away?

Answer (score 0):

**It's probably a simple action.**

Though the action for stowing a weapon isn't explicitly detailed in the core rulebook, it can be inferred from the "reactive myomer pack" item in the Hard Targets book that stowing an item is usually *not* a free action; the pack's text states on page 186,

> Storing an item in the pack is a Free Action, as the pack will automatically grab and stow any item held to the opening by the wearer.

From this, it can be inferred that stowing an item is either a simple or complex action. A simple action seems more likely for sake of parallelism.